# How to use webpack require with 'no-any' tslint rule?

Tags: typescript, webpack, tslint, ionic4

I used ionic to generate an ionic 4 project: `ionic start app sidemenu --type=angular`.
I now want to make the linting rules more strict and introduced `'no-any'`.
But unfortunately the linting fails.
It gives me:

```
$ ng lint app
Linting "app"...

ERROR: ./src/test.ts[10, 24]: Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety. Consider replacing it with a more precise type.

Lint errors found in the listed files.
```

The problem is this line:

```
declare const require: any;
```

Of this file:

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

I suspect that `require` is provided by webpack.
If I understand correctly, it should be declared in `@types/webpack/index.d.ts` and I must include it from `webpack`, which will in turn look it up in the `@types`.
However, I can't find it being declared [there](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/webpack/index.d.ts)

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#code-splitting-and-loading-other-resources) is what you  require?

Comment: Hmm... that function is not providing the `context` function, which is called in this line `const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);`, could it still be the correct one?

Comment: Ahh, do I have to define that function myself?

Comment: you will probably have to set the exact type instead of any.. something like the link

Comment: I created a definition for that function that seems to work, [here](https://gist.github.com/hvoecking/8a461b62b8346448a6b1dad56f78d21a) is a gist of it. Is that the way to go?

Comment: I think it depends on how many cases of `any` you need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` is a part of CommonJS (CJS) module system. Typings for `require` can be found either in the `@types/node` or `@types/webpack-env` package. Install one of them from npm:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

Comment: Installing `@types/node` or `@types/webpack-env` satisfies tslint, but when executing the test, I'm getting `ERROR in src/test.ts(17,25): error TS2339: Property 'context' does not exist on type 'NodeRequire'.` The types of `webpack-env` seem to have a definition of the `context` function, so I also tried `import require from 'webpack-env';` but that gives me a bunch of these errors: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Ok, I got it to work, I had to `import RequireFunction from 'webpack-env';` and `declare const require: RequireFunction;`, thank you!